# Position two arrows to the left and right of the text

Tags: html, css

I want to put two arrows around the text in the code below (to the left and right of the text):

```js
const contrast = document.getElementById("contrast");

function contrastShow(text) {
  contrast.innerHTML = text;
  contrast.classList.add("contrastShow");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastHide");
}

contrastShow("This is the text");
```

```css
.contrast-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.vertical-center-contrast {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73.5vh; /*top: 82vh;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.contrast {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Vazir";
    direction: rtl;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
    opacity: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.contrastShow {
    animation: contrastAnimeShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeShow {
  0%    { opacity: 0; top: 4vh }
  100%  { opacity: 1; top: 1.2vh }
}

.left-arrow {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class ="vertical-center-contrast contrast-container">
       <span class="left-arrow">&#8250;</span>
           <p id="contrast" class="contrast"></p>
           <span class="right-arrow">&#8249;</span>
</div>
```

I create two spans with html code of arrows to create arrows and text in-line with no luck...

Comment: set `display: inline` to the paragraph

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to do this. The most easy way is to add `display: flex;` to your `vertical-center-contrast`

```js
const contrast = document.getElementById("contrast");

function contrastShow(text) {
  contrast.innerHTML = text;
  contrast.classList.add("contrastShow");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastHide");
}

contrastShow("This is the text");
```

```css
.contrast-container {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  /*outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;*/
}

.vertical-center-contrast {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  /*top: 73.5vh;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
}

.contrast {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Vazir";
    direction: rtl;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2vw;
    color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
    opacity: 1;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.left-arrow {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class ="vertical-center-contrast contrast-container">
       <span class="right-arrow">&#8249;</span>
       <p id="contrast" class="contrast">ddd</p>
       <span class="left-arrow">&#8250;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: And how to lower the space between each arrow and text..?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the arrows with an invisible element, then position them with [`justify-content`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/).

```js
const contrast = document.getElementById("contrast");

function contrastShow(text) {
  contrast.innerHTML = text;
  contrast.classList.add("contrastShow");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastHide");
}

contrastShow("This is the text");
```

```css
.contrast-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

.vertical-center-contrast {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73.5vh;
  /*top: 82vh;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.contrast {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Vazir";
  direction: rtl;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.contrastShow {
  animation: contrastAnimeShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.arrows {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeShow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 4vh
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1.2vh
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-center-contrast contrast-container">
  <div class="arrows">
    <span class="right-arrow">&#8249;</span>
    <span class="left-arrow">&#8250;</span>
  </div>
  <p id="contrast" class="contrast">Some text</p>
</div>
```

### If you want space between each arrow (and text), you can use:

```js
const contrast = document.getElementById("contrast");

function contrastShow(text) {
  contrast.innerHTML = text;
  contrast.classList.add("contrastShow");
  contrast.classList.remove("contrastHide");
}

contrastShow("Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text");
```

```css
.contrast-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 11;
  position: relative;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

.vertical-center-contrast {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73.5vh;
  /*top: 82vh;*/
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.contrast {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Vazir";
  direction: rtl;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  left: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.contrastShow {
  animation: contrastAnimeShow 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.arrows {
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

@-webkit-keyframes contrastAnimeShow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 4vh
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 1.2vh
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-center-contrast contrast-container">
  <div class="arrows">
    <span class="right-arrow">&#8249;</span>
    <span class="left-arrow">&#8250;</span>
  </div>
  <p id="contrast" class="contrast"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... plus one... And how to lower the space between each arrow and text..?

Comment: Just add `width: calc(100% - 20px); left: 10px;` to `.arrows`.

Comment: I changed the answer above ^

Comment: That's exactly the issue... if we have a longer text it'll overlap with the arrows...

Comment: Fixed it, see above ^